# Javascript displaying form

Tags: javascript, html

I am a new user here.

I have a HTML file with a button, that when pressed I want to display a form **in the same div**. I have used `document.write()` on the click event, but this turns the webpage entirely white and doesn't display the form in the same div the button is in.

Does anybody know what I need to do to display a form when the button is clicked?

**Javascript code:**

```
    function addListeners()
{
        document.getElementById('button').addEventListener("click", change_border);

    function change_border()
    {
    document.write("form here");
    }

}
window.addEventListener("load", addListeners);
```

**HTML code:**

```
<button id="button" style="margin-left:5%;">Change Profile Picture</button>
```

- I do not want the page to refresh.

Do I need to learn AJAX?

Comment: What have you tried? Show the code. [Please read this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Ok, I will edit my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This doesn't require AJAX at all.

You can place the form in the div and then use CSS on the form to make it hidden.

```
div form#theform {
    display: none;
}
```

Then, you can display the form (overriding the CSS) on the click of the button.

```
<button onclick="showForm()">Press me</button>
```

And this is the JS:

```
function showForm() {
    document.getElementById("theform").style.display = "block";
}
```

Comment: So do I write the entire form in the JavaScript function `getElementById()`? Or can I store the form in a variable and pass it through `getElementById()`?

Comment: If you store the `form`'s `id` in a variable, you can pass the variable in to `getElementById()`

Comment: Thank you, it did indeed help, and everything is working fine!

Answer (score 0):

Zack. document.write will clear the whole page (if it has already loaded) it is a pretty old command. You could set a class on the form which will hide it and then when the button is clicked, either through Jquery or plain JS remove that class so it is visible

Answer (score 0):

try to add these lines to the function,

```
function change_border()
{
document.getElementById("form1").style.display = "block";
}
```